# Swap column values across 2 different tables

Tags: mysql, swap

I have two tables and need to swap the values of a column in each table - I can do this when they are in the same table but when I try to do this with different tables then the second value is already overwritten so gets lost.

For example:

```
table1

id user_id currency   col2    col3......
1  1       10         Bob     2018-04-16
2  2       150        Tom     2018-05-17
3  3       60         Phil    2018-06-04
4  4       125        Jon     2017-12-01
5  5       35         Mike    2018-07-21

table2

id user_id salary     col2    col3......
1  1       USD        16      Active
2  2       USD        17      Active
3  3       GBP        21      Left
4  4       CAD        16      Active
5  5       AUD        19      Active
```

I need these to look like:

```
table1

id user_id currency   col2    col3......
1  1       USD        Bob     2018-04-16
2  2       USD        Tom     2018-05-17
3  3       GBP        Phil    2018-06-04
4  4       CAD        Jon     2017-12-01
5  5       AUD        Mike    2018-07-21

table2

id user_id salary     col2    col3......
1  1       10         16      Active
2  2       150        17      Active
3  3       60         21      Left
4  4       125        16      Active
5  5       35         19      Active
```

I tried:

```
UPDATE table1 t1, table2 t2 
SET t1.currency=t2.salary, t2.salary=t1.currency 
WHERE t1.user_id=t2.user_id;
```

but this does not work (currency gets set correctly but not the salary), is it possible to do?

[Swap two columns values between two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49193266/swap-two-columns-values-between-two-tables) looked like a possible solution but the solution is changing table names as all the columns need swopped whereas I only need single columns swapped.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need to use a mix of both DDL and DML to do this.

First off you'll need to rename one of the columns to be swapped and add a column to hold the new value:

```
alter table table1 change currency salary int;
alter table table1 add currency varchar(3) after salary;
```

then update each table independently:

```
update table1 t1, table2 t2
set t1.currency = t2.salary
where t1.user_id = t2.user_id;

update table1 t1, table2 t2
set t2.salary = t1.salary
where t1.user_id = t2.user_id;
```

and finally remove the extra column:

```
alter table table1 drop salary;
```